# I want to split zip file with python and then join splited files together, I found this code but I can not join splited files

Tags: python-3.x, split, zip

Thank you to @Jeronimo

### [Split a zip archive into multiple chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52193680/split-a-zip-archive-into-multiple-chunks)

```
outfile = archive_name
packet_size = int(1.5 * 1024**3)   # bytes

with open(outfile, "rb") as output:
    filecount = 0
    while True:
        data = output.read(packet_size)
        print(len(data))
        if not data:
            break   # we're done
        with open("{}{:03}".format(outfile, filecount), "wb") as packet:
            packet.write(data)
        filecount += 1
```

---

after splitting them I can not join them together

Answer (score 0):

### Fortunately, I solve this problem my self

```
outfile = "archive_name"
packet_size = int(1024*1024*100)   # bytes
filenumbers=9   #number of files you want to join
for i in range(filenumbers):
    with open("{}.zip{:03}".format(outfile, i), "rb") as packet:
        col=packet.read(packet_size)

        with open("{}02.zip".format(outfile), "ab+") as mainpackage:
            mainpackage.write(col)
```

---