# How to use Python to split and compress a folder into multiple volumes, with the ability to display a progress bar and set the volume size

Tags: python, zip

Why is this problem present?

Usually, I play some games, and these games are typically quite large. When I want to upload them to a cloud storage service, the single compressed file can reach sizes of dozens of gigabytes, making it inconvenient for uploading.

I hope to split these games into smaller compressed volumes, each roughly 1GB in size, to make downloading and uploading easier.
As shown in the following image：
[image]

As a Python enthusiast, whenever I encounter problems, I always consider if there's a Python solution. However, what frustrates me is that I haven't found one. I've tried modules like shutil and zipfile, but they haven't resolved my issue. Does anyone know a solution for this?

I know of some third-party tools, for example, `360zip`, `7zip`, or Linux shell commands that can solve this problem, but I would prefer a Pythonic solution.

Comment: you can always use `subprocess.run()` to execute external program like `7zip` or `rar`

Comment: I'm not sure if `zip` can create splited files -so module `zipfile` can't create them. Eventually you may try to create one big `zip` and later split it to smaller part using standard `open()` `read()` `write()` - but later you will need own code to join it back to one big `zip`

Comment: anwswers in this question uses `subprocess` to run `7zip` or `open() read() write()` to split file   [python 3.x - Split a zip archive into multiple chunks - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52193680/split-a-zip-archive-into-multiple-chunks)